# AChartEngine - MathHelper.getLabels() generating wrong labels

Tags: android, achartengine

```
StartValue = 0.0;
EndValue = 700.0;
StepValue = 100.0;
```

When I am using these values to generate Labels Using method

```
MathHelper.getLabels(StartValue, EndValue, StepValue);
```

It generates 71 labels (Starting from 0.0 to 700.0 with step of 10.0) instead of 8 labels.

I don't know why this happening.

Help needed.

Thanks in advance.

Below is my code :

```
double yAxisStart = 0.0;
double yAxisEnd = 700.0;
int yAxisStep = 100.0;
List<Double> labels = MathHelper.getLabels(yAxisStart, yAxisEnd, yAxisStep);
mRenderer.clearYTextLabels();
for (Double label : labels) {
    mRenderer.addYTextLabel(label, "" + label);
}
mRenderer.setYLabels(0);
```

Output I wanted is :

```
0.0
100.0
200.0
300.0
```

and so on.

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MathHelper.getLabels()` parameters are `start`, `end` and `approxNumLabels`. There isn't any `step` value. The third parameter is an indication of an approximate number of labels you need it to return. If it makes sense to return 70 labels, it won't return you 100 that make no sense.

However, I suggest you use the `renderer.setYLabels(yLabels)` method instead.

Comment: Yes, you are right third parameter is not a step it is approximate number of labels. I misunderstand it.